# How To Add PHP Library To Netbeans?

Tags: php, netbeans

I am creating a PHP library of the functions and snippets I use most.
I am trying to set the library project up so that I can use it across other projects.
Currently I have it in the global include folder and the autocomplete for my functions is working well.
However when I run the functions I receive an error because they are not included how do I go about finding them to include them. Or is there a way for me to auto copy them into the source folder of the second project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add path to your library into `include_path` in your php.ini

Comment: I would like to be able to do this in netbeans not on the server side. Unless there is a way to do it in netbeans I don't know about?

Comment: You are using Netbeans on a computer which is separate from the computer that hosts the website, correct? The web-server doesn't know *anything* about how your Netbeans is set up, all it knows it the project files which you upload or store on the serer. They are completely separate configurations. Putting a JPEG file as your desktop background does not mean that a web-server has the same JPEG file. Ditto for libraries.

Comment: I was hoping that I could setup something similar to user libraries in Eclipse I guess not. Thanks for the info.